# Expand Canvas and Extend Edges of Image to Fill It

Tags: software, photoshop, photo-editing, gimp, rescaling

Hopefully this is the right place to ask this type of question. I am editing a digital photo (in gimp), and need to increase canvas size slightly.

At one point, I was watching a tutorial where they extended the canvas and did something to scale only the edges of the image to fill that extra canvas i.e. without distorting or scaling the main area of the image at all, and the result was almost un-detectible.

I don't remember what that feature/technique was called or how they did it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I found the video I was watching where this was done. I don't have the software used in the tutorial, and I am hoping there is some way to do it in something like Gimp, etc.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/how-to/straighten-photos-content-aware-fill.html

Comment: If I remember correctly, before "*content aware fill*" there was "*content aware scale*" introduced in some previous version of PS, which allowed to scale the background without scaling the foreground. Maybe this is sufficient for you and you have access to some older version of PS that has this feature? I think they also introduced "*content aware move*" later.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search led me to a tool in GIMP called the "Resynthesizer Tool," which is apparently GIMP's version of Photoshop's Content-Aware Fill. Here's a video tutorial on using the Resynthesizer Tool.  Hope that helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEV0X5WNRVY